# Trouble getting Ruby on Rails yield to work in the UI layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am following this tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html and trying to separate the header div from the rest of the HTML templates.

I have taken out a div from my app/views/home/index.html.erb file and replaced it with

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

Then I made a file called head.html.erb in the /app/views/layouts directory and put that div in there.  Then I put this code around the div:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't work and the header div does not get displayed.  Where did I go wrong? I think there is a path and directory mismatch, but I am not sure exactly how to match them up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout is where you put the `yield` call, and each view's template is where you put the `content_for` block. You'll probably want your `yield` call in your application's main layout file.

So in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` put this where you want it to be:

```
<div id="my_header_div">
  <%= yield :head %>
</div>
```

Then in each view, you can do this:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <h1>My Header!</h1>
<% end %>
```

And it will insert inside the div in your layout file.

Comment: I switched it up and now have this "<%= yield :head %>" in my index.html.erb but it is not rendering the div.  Does it just know to look for head.html.erb ?

Comment: No, the `yield` should be in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file, which all other views use by default. Then in your templates (like your `index.html.erb` file) you put the `content_for` block.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the purpose of the application.html.rb file.  Is it just to keep track of possible divs and css/js files I can import in my templates?  And the templates have the code?

Comment: Yes, by default your `application.html.erb` file should contain a single `<%= yield %>` call in it, which is where the contents of your templates (like `index.html.erb`) get inserted. So you can add other `yield` calls in that layout file too, and then use `content_for` in your templates to insert the content in the appropriate place. So the `yield :head` call you see at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield is actually in the application layout file, not the `index.html.erb` file.

Comment: @ dmarkow But if the code goes into the template, then it isn't much of a template in a traditional sense, right?  I mean the whole point is that the template would be reused.  But if I have code specific to a page in the template, then I have to make a new template for each page.  I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

You should put this:

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

in your layout file

If your `head` layout is not layout for your particular action `content_for :head` will never work